# MySQL database table is not being updated

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

my database table is not inserted with this information and I can't see where the error is, and if the insert is even successful or not. Please help!

```
        try{ 

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.employee_info(employeeID, FirstName, LastName, Admin,DOB,Address,Email,HourlyRate,Gender,ALeaveBalance,SLeaveBalance,ActiveStatus,Role,BSB,BankName,AccNumber,SuperNumber,SuperCompany) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
             ps.setString(1, employee_id);
             ps.setString(2, firstName);
             ps.setString(3, lastName);
             ps.setString(4, admin);
             ps.setString(5, DOB);
             ps.setString(6, address);
             ps.setString(7, email);
             ps.setString(8, HPR);
             ps.setString(9, gender);
             ps.setString(10, ALB);
             ps.setString(11, SLB);
             ps.setString(12, Role);
             ps.setString(13, BSB);
             ps.setString(14, BankName);
             ps.setString(15, BAN);
             ps.setString(16, SAC);
             ps.setString(17, SAN);
             ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
             st=rs.next(); 
             if(st) { 
                 out.println("Account successfully created!");
                 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html"); 
                 rd.include(request, response);
             }
             else{ 
                 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("changePassAdmin.html"); 
                 rd.include(request, response);
             }
         }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      out.close();
```

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? Please post the stacktrace

Comment: @Funtik This is a web application. When I press the submit button in the html (which has form action to this servlet), it just shows a blank page with the url of this servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeQuery` is only used for queries,  you need to write

```
 ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Comment: I'm getting an error Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to ResultSet

Comment: read the Javadoc. `executeUpdate` does not return a `ResultSet` (what should be in the result set ? - you are not executing a query) but the number of affected records as int. For your insert you want to get a 1.

Comment: Thanks it works! I'll accept your answer, but can you please tell me how to print("Successful") if update was done successfully? I've updated my code above to show you the changes.

Comment: `int count = ps.executeUpdate(); if (count == 1) { out.println("success"); ...`

Comment: I made a rollback to your edit because it was hiding the original question and problem. You can always ask new questions...

Comment: and if it wasn't a success then use else{ ?

Comment: And in that case, what's the purpose of catch(Exception e)?